# static pages that dont break?

Tags: css

Hi I want to do a fixed size page, but don't want the page to break or reflow at all if the user resizes the window. Is this a javascript function?

sample: http://www.neimanmarcus.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people put all the content of there page inside a div with an id, such as 'doc', then they would apply the following rule:

```
<body><div id="doc">
YOUR PAGE HERE
</div></body>
```

```
body {
test-align: center;
}

#doc {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
width: 940px
}
```

The "text-align" fixes an IE 6 issue, really you just need to assign a margin to your wrapping document div.

Comment: oh, duh, I had a page where a rtow of images were breaking, but did't apply a fixed width to them.  Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't need java script function .
but remember : don't use % for declaring width or height for elements in css.(for having a static element that resizing window doesn't effect that).
 for example : "width:90%;" ==> replace this with "width:100px;"